# Migrating a postgres table from one server to another

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to migrate the contents of a table from one postgres server to another.

The table structure is identical on both databases, but the database name and user name is different.

On my source database I use this command to export the table contents...

```
pg_dump -a -U postgres -d postgres -t clust -f f:\dump\clust.dump.psql
```

This is connecting as user 'postgres' to database 'postgres' and dumping the contents of the table 'clust' to the specified file.

I then copy the file to the destination server and attempt to use the following to restore it....

```
pg_restore -a -U testapp -d testdb -t clust -f f:\dump\clust.dump.psql
```

The command is very similar to the pg_dump, except that this time the database is called 'testdb' and the username is 'testapp'.

This generates the error....

```
pg_restore: options -d/--dbname and -f/--file cannot be used together
```

How do I get around this? Without the file definition the command won't know where to restore from, and without the database name it won't know which one to connect to?

NOTE - both machines are windows, running the same version of postgres. They're not networked together so data is transferred by connecting a removable drive into each machine in turn.

Comment: `pg_dump` creates a SQL script. You need to run that with `psql`

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name - I must remember to read the small print next time - I assumed that pg_dump and pg_restore were reciprocal functions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html)

> Dumps can be output in script or archive file formats. Script dumps are plain-text files containing the SQL commands required to reconstruct the database to the state it was in at the time it was saved. **To restore from such a script, feed it to [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)**.

And then further down:

> -F format
> --format=format
>
> Selects the format of the output. format can be one of the following:
>
> p
> plain
> Output a plain-text SQL script file (**the default**).
>
> c
> custom
> Output a custom-format archive *suitable for input into pg_restore*.

As you didn't specify a format, it's a plain text dump - a SQL script that needs to be run through `psql`